# Algorithm/method for grouping items based on their relative distance

Tags: python, algorithms, machine-learning, classification

I'm looking for a method to classify a set of items based on their relative distance.

For example assume we have 4 cities and we know their relative distance:

| city1 | city2 | city3 | city4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.1 | 2.2 | 3.4 |
| 2.1 | 0 | 2.2 | 2.1 |
| 2.2 | 2.2 | 0 | 1.4 |
| 3.4 | 2.1 | 1.4 | 0 |

If we try to categorize these 4 cities into two categories, intuitively we'll end up with

```
(city1, city2) and (city3, city4)
```

by minimizing the inner distance between cities.

Based on my understanding of K-Means, this method works when we have a common distance metric to say X-axis. Here, we don't know how the distance is calculated, so there isn't a clear way to decompose distance to something in common.

Is there a method to categorize these cities?

Comment: mm I intuitively had say that (city1) and (city2,city3,city4) is a better grouping but. that depends only in the way you evaluate "distances".

Comment: If you know that they are approximately Euclidean, you could try triangulation? Just pick a random direction to start.

Comment: @Woodford thanks for the tip, posted there

Comment: @Neil I'm looking for a way to categorize close cities, not sure how triangulation can help.

Comment: @Neil A<->B + B<->C != A<->C

Comment: You can try *minimum spanning tree clusterization*, https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/mst.pdf

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Do you know of any Python implementation of this algorithm?

Comment: @Mehdi Zare: *minimum spanning tree clusterization* can be implemented via *Kruskal's algorithm*

Comment: If you want to use k-means, add the cities one-by-one, make up coördinates based on constraints from the distances to the average existing cities? MST is a totally better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try solving the task as a *graph* problem. Let city be *vertex* and road between city be *edge*.
Then you can use [minimum spanning tree clusterization](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/mst.pdf): you start building *minimum spanning tree*, but
stop in the middle of the process when you have required number of clusters.

Let's do it with a help of [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm)

1. We start from **4** clusters: `{city1}, {city2}, {city3}, {city4}`
2. We get the shortest edge, it is `city3 - city4` (`1.4`), we *eliminate* it and have **3** clusters:
   `{city1}, {city2}, {city3, city4}`
3. We get the next shortest edge: it is either `city1 - city1` or `city2 - city4` (both has `2.1` length) depending on
   tie resolution we have **2** clusters: either `{city1, city2}, {city3, city4}` or
   `{city1}, {city2, city3, city4}`
4. Here (at **2** clusters) we stop and get either `{city1, city2}, {city3, city4}` or  `{city1}, {city2, city3, city4}` clusterization

You can use a little bit *less efficient*, but *easy to code* approach:

1. Build *minimum spanning tree* by any algorithm (Kruskal's, Prim's) by any library (say, `scipy`)
2. Now you have all the cities in one cluster
3. Start dropping the longest edges from this tree: with one longest edge dropped you'll get **2** clusters (subtrees), with **k** longest edges removed - **k + 1** clusters.